# Swift - jonkykong SideMenu UISideMenuNavigationController not found

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have downloaded `jonkykong SideMenu` using `Carthage` and I imported the `framework` inside my project as the image below

[image]

When I try to define the `custom class` of the `navigation controller` in my `storyboard` to `UISideMenuNavigationController` as I need to do following the instructions of the library on [GitHub](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu) the class doesn't is not found as image below:

[image]

The `framework` in working fine when I import it inside a `swift file`.

How can I reference this class inside the `storyboard`

Comment: Did you set the `Module` to `SideMenu`?

Comment: Yes I did. And it didn't work.

Comment: I think you should check their example:
https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/tree/master/Example
Also try relaunch xcode and check if the library could be imported to some view controller.

Comment: I am able to import the library to a view controller programmatically but it doesn't appear as a custom class in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I set up the configuration manually even the XCode not finding it.

Image below:
[image]